# how can i build static server & websocket server in one exe file by pkg

Tags: websocket, staticresource

I want build static resource server and websocket server into one exe file.
using the open source package [pkg](https://github.com/zeit/pkg).
but official documentation have not example.

I have a web app, and a websocket server, for demo, it's should running in a pc without node.js environment.
so, the best practice is building these to a .exe file.

```
 {
  "bin": "server/index.js",
  "pkg": {
    "assets": [
      "built/**/*"
    ]
  }
}
```

seem like good, but I don't know how to config websocket server.
     for terminal result, click the .exe file, it's have two window: 
     one for static resource server
     other for websocket server

Comment: Thanks @Sunny  for check language program and typo.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was resolved.

Code:

```
// static resource server
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/built/packaged/'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html', err => console.log(err));
});
```

then, embed the child_process for open a new websocket server:

```
const child_process = require('child_process');
child_process.exec(`node ./my-websocket.js --direction="C:/Users/"`, (err, stdout, 
  stderr) =>  { // ...});
```